# Estimating bias and confidence for a 3-sided die

Tags: probability, statistics

Say there is a 3-sided die w/ the values {1, 2, 3}. **I don't know the bias of each side**. How many times(n times) must I roll the die to estimate the bias of every side within +-0.1 with a probability of at least 90%?

I think I understood how this question would work with a **two-sided coin**, where X is the expected value after n tosses. In particular:
$$X= \sum \frac{(X_i)}{n}, X_i \in [0, 1]$$
By Hoeffding's inequality, $$2e^{-2n\epsilon ^2} \leq \delta=>  n \geq \frac{ln(2/\delta)}{2\epsilon^2}$$

Then, we can substitute $\delta=0.1, \epsilon = 0.1 $ to find n, the number of times you need to toss the coin.

How would this work for a 3-sided die? I thought of treating each side as a coin toss, so you are throwing 3 coins in a way. How do I continue?

Comment: That is not the tightest of bounds (it suggests $n \ge 150$ when in two-sided coin case it turns out $n\ge 76$ would do).  In the three-sided case I suspect the number required is slightly higher than the two-sided case, but empirically substantially less than $150$

Comment: Where is the error? Also, how would I apply this to a 3-sided die?

Comment: It is not an error, just a loose inequality

Comment: I understand. I think I'm OK with it not being tight as this is just a conceptual problem. For a 3-sided die, I thought about using an indicator for every side that'll "count" the number of times the die has landed on every side. However, I'm not sure how to continue.